# How do you select the channel to record when using an external usb audio input?

Tags: ios, core-audio

Background: Using core audio, remoteio, (no graph)
I have successfully used the built in mic for reading in samples just fine.  I have recently added code to change the audio source via a notification (audio route change).  I can switch to the USB input with no problem and read in samples fine.

My issue is that I am always reading samples from the first channel.   So I can only read in from the first channel of the built in mic and the first channel of the external usb.

**I am seeking help on how to read from the higher channels of the usb.**  I only need to read in one channel at a time and have no need to read in multiple input channels at once.

My thinking was to `AudioUnitSetProperty` with `kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO` 
kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO but it crashes when I do that and it is difficult to debug since I cannot be tethered to xcode while debugging since the ios device is connected via usb to the external usb audio.  Do I need to disable audio first?  stop session?

Comment: do you have some code you can show? or (even better) an example project on github?

Comment: When you use external audio interfaces you can debug your app by using Wi-Fi; in Xcode -> Devices -> Connect to Network.